# Convert between a reference to a trait and a struct that implements that trait in Rust

Tags: rust

I have a trait and a struct that implements that trait:

```
trait A {
    fn something(&self);
}

struct B {
    some_field: i32,
}

impl A for B {
    fn something(&self) {}
}
```

There is a part of my code where I have an `&A`, and I know it is an instance of `B`, I would like to cast `&A` to `&B`. How can I accomplish this? So far, I have tried first casting to `*const A` and then casting to `*const B`, but I can't figure out how to go from `*const B` to `&B`.

After playing around with some things, I think this is correct?

```
fn some_func(a: &dyn A) {
    let a_ptr = a as *const A;
    let b_ptr = a_ptr as *const B;
    unsafe { let b = &*b_ptr as &B; }
}
```

Comment: "After playing around with some things, I think this is correct?" this is not really how I will call this kind of thing in rust. But yes this will "compile"

Comment: Maybe if you added a bit of the code that produces the `A` we could find a way around the problem.

Comment: If you have an `&A`, and you *know* it is an instance of `B`, why can't you prove that it is -- i.e., use `&B`?

Comment: @trentcl my code would be provable with tagged unions, but Rust doesn't have such functionality. I could probably use an enum, but that seems like a less fun way to write the code.

Comment: Sure, "fun" is one way to describe undefined behavior.

Comment: `enum` is what Rust calls a tagged union…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this safely is by adding a method `fn any(&self) -> &Any` to your trait, which carries type information and makes it possible to perform a checked downcast to an arbitrary type (in this case `B`).

```
use std::any::Any;

trait A {
    fn something(&self);
    fn any(&self) -> &Any;
}

struct B {
    some_field: i32,
}

impl A for B {
    fn something(&self) {}
    fn any(&self) -> &Any {
        self
    }
}

fn some_func(a: &dyn A) {
    let b: &B = a.any().downcast_ref().unwrap();
}
```